# chi-square - two sample test in r

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, p-value

There is in R a function to perform a chi-square two sample test ?http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/chi2samp.htm

For example I whant to prove if x = rnorm(100) and y = rnorm(100) come from the same distribution.

I tried to use the chisq.test function, but I think it is not correct because it gives me a very large p-value

```
> chisq.test(rnorm(100),runif(100))

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  rnorm(100) and runif(100)
X-squared = 9900, df = 9801, p-value = 0.239
```

thank you

Comment: I would normally only use `chisq.test` for binary/categorical data. Can you be more specific about what a "chi-square two sample test" is, do you have some other name for it?

Comment: [link](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/chi2samp.htm)

Comment: Reading your link, it looks like it's the same as `chisq.test`, and is intended for binned/categorical data. You can try `ks.test` which is intended for continuous data but a lot of people think it's not particularly useful.

Comment: You're misusing `chisq.test` - the `x` and `y` arguments to the function are used to tabulate against one another. So `chisq.test(x=rep(1:2,each=5), y=rep(1:2,each=5))` and `chisq.test(x=table(rep(1:2,each=5),rep(1:2,each=5)))` are equivalent. In addition to the fact that it is not a test for use with continuous data as Marius notes.

Comment: From what I understand from the link, you could create a matrix which would be a contingency table of counts of `x` and `y` in a series of bins, and then perform `chisq.test` on this matrix. But I've never heard of this test before. And it seems to be very dependent on the size of the bins. As @Marius said, you'd probably be better off using a `ks.test`.

Comment: More discussion here - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83163/statistical-test-to-tell-whether-two-samples-are-pulled-from-the-same-population

Comment: In case you wanna try it: `hx=hist(x,br=seq(floor(min(x)),ceiling(max(x)),by=1),plot=F)$counts;
hy=hist(y,br=seq(floor(min(x)),ceiling(max(x)),by=1),plot=F)$counts;
m=as.matrix(rbind(hx,hy)); chisq.test(m);` Though I can't vouch for the statistical soundness..

Comment: @Lamia - That's just darn clever. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar data - binned length frequencies of fish from two different sampling methods. Because my data are binned, as I understand it, it is not appropriate to use the KS test, because that test requires continuous data. So, I too, came across the Chi Square two sample test offered by DataPlot at the link you provide: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/chi2samp.htm

I installed the Dataplot software, and communicated with the contact person for the test when I had problems. I've also run it in R, and gotten the same result (a good check). Here's what I coded in R:

> col1=c(2,4,22,46,81,103,238,65,82,9,58,2)
>   col2=c(0,0,1,1,0,10,32,22,20,4,0,0)
>   chisq.test(cbind(col1,col2))

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test
```

data:  cbind(col1, col2)
X-squared = 53.782, df = 11, p-value = 1.293e-07

NOTE: Dataplot did not mind if I had a bin that had zeros for both of my samples, but R does - after much frustration I realized this, removed the shared 0s, and R gave me the same test stat, df, and p value that I got with DataPlot. Hope this helps!