# How to do Chi-Sqr Test on a tibble/dataframe in R

Tags: r, statistics, tidyverse, chi-squared

I have consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036740/chi-square-two-sample-test-in-r) but can't get it to work.

Here is my tibble:

```
Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
Groups: word [10]

        word Detractor Passive Promoter
*      <chr>     <int>   <int>    <int>
1  broadband       833     766      507
2       call       441     348      118
3    cheaper       641     949      182
4   customer      1563    1128      758
5   internet       297     277      195
6       line       389     392      182
7      price      1022    1212      549
8   reliable       230     316      743
9    service      1546    1231     2119
10     speed       262     228      194
```

This is what I have tried:

```
csv%>%
      select(word,NPS_Level,total_word_count_by_cust)%>%
      spread(NPS_Level,total_word_count_by_cust)%>%
      rowwise()%>% 
  mutate(
    test_stat = chisq.test(c(word, Detractor))$statistic,
    p_val = chisq.test(c(word, Detractor))$p.value
    )
```

getting the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

here is the `dput()` output:

```
structure(list(word = c("broadband", "call", "cheaper", "customer", 
"internet", "line", "price", "reliable", "service", "speed"), 
    Detractor = c(833L, 441L, 641L, 1563L, 297L, 389L, 1022L, 
    230L, 1546L, 262L), Passive = c(766L, 348L, 949L, 1128L, 
    277L, 392L, 1212L, 316L, 1231L, 228L), Promoter = c(507L, 
    118L, 182L, 758L, 195L, 182L, 549L, 743L, 2119L, 194L)), .Names = c("word", 
"Detractor", "Passive", "Promoter"), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), vars = list(
    word), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    word = c("broadband", "call", "cheaper", "customer", "internet", 
    "line", "price", "reliable", "service", "speed")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), vars = list(word), drop = TRUE, .Names = "word"))
```

is there a way I could show the results of all variables the way Minitab does?
i.e.

```
    Chi-Square Test for Association: word, Worksheet columns 

Rows: word   Columns: Worksheet columns

             Detractor  Passive  Promoter    All

broadband          833      766       507   2106
                 775.5    735.0     595.5
                 4.263    1.305    13.145

call               441      348       118    907
                 334.0    316.6     256.5
                34.288    3.123    74.749

cheaper            641      949       182   1772
                 652.5    618.5     501.0
                 0.203  176.664   203.145

customer          1563     1128       758   3449
                1270.0   1203.8     975.2
                67.579    4.768    48.378

internet           297      277       195    769
                 283.2    268.4     217.4
                 0.675    0.276     2.315

line               389      392       182    963
                 354.6    336.1     272.3
                 3.335    9.296    29.939

price             1022     1212       549   2783
                1024.8    971.3     786.9
                 0.008   59.642    71.921

reliable           230      316       743   1289
                 474.7    449.9     364.5
               126.103   39.842   393.147

service           1546     1231      2119   4896
                1802.9   1708.8    1384.3
                36.598  133.590   389.870

speed              262      228       194    684
                 251.9    238.7     193.4
                 0.407    0.482     0.002

All               7224     6847      5547  19618

Cell Contents:      Count
                    Expected count
                    Contribution to Chi-square


Pearson Chi-Square = 1929.058, DF = 18, P-Value = 0.000
Likelihood Ratio Chi-Square = 1898.013, DF = 18, P-Value = 0.000
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @Jimbou added the `dput()` output

Comment: `rownames(dat) = dat$word ; chisq.test(dat[-1])` gives the counts / expected counts.

Comment: @user20650 what is `dat`? when I do `csv%>%
      select(word,NPS_Level,total_word_count_by_cust)%>%
      spread(NPS_Level,total_word_count_by_cust)%>%
      row.names(word)` it gives the error: `Error in row.names(., word) : unused argument (word)`

Comment: Your dput didnt work for me (perhaps because i dont have these tidy packages installed), but if your data is a dataframe, (try converting your data with `dat <- as.data.frame(yourtibble)`) the above comment will produce the chisq.test results.

Comment: it worked! it's quite a finniky way to do it. wish we could do it in tidyverse format

Comment: finniky ;), how?? you can apply chisq.test directly on your dataframe which seems ideal

Comment: @user20650 I am just used to tidyverse formats :D Do you know how to extract `Contribution to Chi-square` score? I can get `statistics` and `expected` values but can't seem to find `Contribution to Chi-square` values by variable to the overall test score

Comment: ... `residuals^2`

Answer (score 4):

thanks to comments below, this is how I did it:

To do the Chi-Squared test we need rows and columns by numbers. Then convert the rows column into rownames (Tibble will not allow this so will have to convert it to dataframe before calling the chi-sq method)

```
m = csv%>%
      select(word,NPS_Level,total_word_count_by_cust)%>%
      spread(NPS_Level,total_word_count_by_cust)

rownames(m) = m$word

m <- m%>%
      as.data.frame()

Xsq <- chisq.test(m[-1]) #exclude the row column i.e. word as already converted to rownames
```